# Text processing in R

Tags: r

I have a text file with many lines (first two are shown below)

```
1: 146 189 229 
2: 191 229
```

I need to convert to the output

```
1 146
1 189
1 229
2 191
2 229
```

I have read the lines in loop, removed the ":" and split by " ".

```
fbnet <- readLines("0.egonet")

for (line in fbnet){  
  line <- gsub(":","",line)
  line <- unlist(strsplit(line, " ", fixed = TRUE),use.names=FALSE)
  friend = line[1] 
 }
```

How to proceed next

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can read with `read.csv/read.txt` specifying the delimiter as `:` to output a data.frame with 2 columns and then use `separate_rows` to split the second column ('V2' - when we specify `header = FALSE` - the automatic naming of columns starts with letter `V` followed by sequence of numbers for each column) with space delimiter into separate rows and remove the NA elements (in case there are multiple spaces) with `filter`

```
library(tidyverse)
read.csv(text=fbnet, sep=":", header = FALSE) %>% 
        separate_rows(V2, convert = TRUE) %>%
        filter(!is.na(V2))
   V1  V2
1  1 146
2  1 189
3  1 229
4  2 191
5  2 229
```

Or using `read_delim` from `readr` with `separate_rows` and `filter`

```
read_delim(paste(trimws(fbnet), collapse="\n"), delim=":", col_names = FALSE) %>% 
      separate_rows(X2, convert = TRUE) %>%
      filter(!is.na(X2))
```

#### data

```
fbnet <- readLines(textConnection("1: 146 189 229 
     2: 191 229"))

#if we are reading from file, then 
fbnet <- readLines("file.txt")
```